# OpenCart + OCMOD - How to get the value from custom_fields?

Tags: opencart

I installed and extension called "Display custom fields for OpenCart 3.0.x" to use custom fields needed for my e-commerce.

I need to get the value from these custom fields and set them on "catalog/view/theme/default/template/mail/register_alert.twig" with OCMOD so that when a client makes a sign-up to an account, the value of these custom fields get sent to the admin e-mail in the notification e-mail.

I tried this code:

```
    <!-- Recieves and treats the data from the custom fields in 'controller'-->
    <file path="catalog/controller/mail/register.php">
        <operation>
            <search>
                <![CDATA[$data['lastname'] = $args[0]['lastname'];]]>
            </search>
            <add position="after">
                <![CDATA[
        $this->load->model('account/custom_field');
              $custom_fields = $this->model_account_custom_field->getCustomFields($args[0]['customer_group_id']);
          
              $data['custom_fields'] = $custom_fields;
            $data['custom_field'] = $this->request->post;
              ]]>
              </add>
        </operation>
    </file>
    <file path="catalog/view/theme/default/template/mail/register_alert.twig">
        <!-- Recieves and shows the data from the custom fields in 'view' -->
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[{{ text_telephone }} {{ telephone }}]]></search>
            <add position="after"><![CDATA[
{% for cf in custom_fields %}
{{ cf.name}} : {{ cf_value}}
{% endfor %}
            ]]>
            </add>
        </operation>
    </file>
```

But this code only calls to the name of the custom field and doesn't show me the value.

I'm still learning, can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have solved it but it seems you have a typo:

> {{ cf.name}} : {{ **cf_value**}}

It should be:

> {{ cf.name}} : {{ **cf.value**}}